# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: node.js, angular, macos, webpack, sass

Working with:

Angular CLI: 17.2.3

Node: 18.13.0

Package Manager: npm 8.19.3

OS: darwin x64

Angular: 12.2.13

I have the error:
`Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.`

In my terminal it looks like:

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "src/theme/variables.scss";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
```

^^^ Those files are there. It's as if it doesn't know that src/ starts at the root???

My tsconfig.json file has:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["assets/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"],
      "crypto": ["./node_modules/crypto-js"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

I have repeatedly tried to delete my /node_modules and `npm install`ed again, but nothing has changed it.

Please, help. No idea what I did to break my sass file imports.

Comment: Make sure the import paths are configured correctly  in theme/variables.scss file.